# Extract array indices that contain a specific value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with the shape: *(31777, 44, 44)*

Its `sum` is 31777.0, and every `(44,44)` grid contains just one 1.0 entry at some coordinates.

My objective is to obtain an array of shape *(31777, 2)* where the `2` are the coordinates of the 1.0 entry in the grid.
The messy way to do this is with a loop, but I'm looking for an elegant performant solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `numpy.where` to find the indexes of elements in multidimensional array, for example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[[1,0],[0,0]], [[0,0],[1,0]], [[0,0], [0,1]]])
arr.shape
# (3, 2, 2)

np.array([coord for coord in zip(*np.where(arr == 1)[1:])])
# array([[0, 0],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 1]]) this is an array of shape (3,2) which contains coordinates of 1.0 entry.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer gave me google material to find what I believe is optimal:

```
np.vstack(arr.nonzero()[1:][::-1]).T
```