# Find the index of a value in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a two dimensional array. If I have one of the values how do I find its corresponding value?
For example:

```
    my_array=[[1,2][3,4][5,6]]
```

If I have the value `4`, how do I get it to tell me `3`? 
I tried

```
my_array.index(4)
```

but it returned this:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Please correct your typo and tell us why you want 3?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `my_array=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`?

Comment: Try `numpy.where`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract array indices that contain a specific value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166890/extract-array-indices-that-contain-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a strange solution, but:

```
for item in my_array:
    if 4 in item:
        print item[abs(item.index(4)-1)]
```

First, check if the item is there. Then, if it is, `abs(item.index(4)-1` will always return the opposite index of the tuple.

Comment: Where do `x` and `y` come from? He wants to find the indexes from the value.

Comment: Okay, that needs to be edited, because he says value twice and it's _very_ confusing.

Comment: Seems very clear to me. He has the value `4`, so it should find the row `[3, 4]`, and return the value in the other column that row, which is `3`.

Comment: @Barmar I think he wants the index in the flattened array

Comment: If there are only two values, then it's a tuple, not a two dimensional array, isn't it? Otherwise, how would you know what values are associated with which?

Comment: Well, it appears to be an Nx2 array.

Comment: I've updated to reflect a new, albeit strange solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
import numpy as np 

my_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[4,6]])
print x
goodvalues = [3, 4, 7]
ix = np.in1d(x.ravel(), goodvalues).reshape(x.shape)
print ix
```

My outputs are...

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [4 6]]
[[False False]
 [ True  True]
 [ True False]]
```

This will return a boolean mask, which contains the indices that contain elements within goodvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
[y for x in my_array for y in x].index(4)
```

Output :

```
3
```